Postgres SQL Join Tables
Question
I have 2 tables with below schema and data:
regular_fee table

id  sellable_id channel_id  customer_fee    subscription_fee    currency_code   posted_date company_id
1   333 123 10  5   usd 2024-03-27  5555
2   333 123 10  5   usd 2024-03-28  5555
3   333 123 10  5   usd 2024-03-29  5555

additional_fee table

id  sellable_id channel_id  base_rate   store_fee   item_vol    currency_code   charge_date company_id
1   333 123 2   50  20  usd 2024-03-27  5555
2   222 123 2   52  20  usd 2024-03-28  5555
3   444 123 2   34  20  usd 2024-03-29  5555

I want to merge these 2 tables so that the final output would look like below:

sellable_id channel_id  customer_fee    subscription_fee    base_rate   store_fee   item_vol    currency_code   date    company_id
333 123 10  5   0   0   0   usd 2024-03-27  5555
333 123 10  5   0   0   0   usd 2024-03-28  5555
333 123 10  5   0   0   0   usd 2024-03-29  5555
333 123 0   0   2   50  20  usd 2024-03-27  5555
222 123 0   0   2   52  20  usd 2024-03-28  5555
444 123 0   0   2   34  20  usd 2024-03-29  5555

a more details explaination:

Tried
I tried to merge them using FULL OUTER JOIN, but the result does not look right. Here's my query
SELECT
    rf.sellable_id,
    rf.channel_id,
    rf.company_id,
    rf.customer_fee,
    rf.subscription_fee,
    af.sellable_id,
    af.channel_id,
    af.company_id,
    af.base_rate,
    af.store_fee,
    af.item_vol
FROM
    regular_fee rf
FULL OUTER JOIN
    additional_fee af
    ON rf.company_id = af.company_id
WHERE
    AND rf.posted_date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-03-31'
    AND af.charge_date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-03-31';

Result be like:

where it auto-populate the col value if not exist, but I don't want to do that.

Please don’t use images as no one can copy your data if they want to try a solution. Add all information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted (e.g. data as tables)

Got it, updated the question with text format

Are you sure you have provided the correct query?

It is the query which does not provide the result I want, the point is that, the query I provided will auto-populate the fields with numbers if the col dose not exist, which is not what i want.

Please format your data as tables, not code, so that they’re readable

for your desired result, you can do something like:
SELECT
    sellable_id,
    channel_id,
    customer_fee,
    subscription_fee,
    0 AS base_rate,
    0 AS store_fee,
    0 AS item_vol,
    currency_code,
    posted_date AS date,
    company_id
FROM
    regular_fee

UNION ALL

SELECT
    sellable_id,
    channel_id,
    0 AS customer_fee,
    0 AS subscription_fee,
    base_rate,
    store_fee,
    item_vol,
    currency_code,
    charge_date AS date,
    company_id
FROM
    additional_fee;

